# Combine rows with different values based on the same ID

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, tidyr

I have a dataset where each ID may have multiple rows with either missing or different values for each variable.

For each variable, I would like to create new columns that consolidate the data across rows for the same ID. The criteria for the new columns is:

- Use values from other rows for the same ID if the values for all rows are consistent for the variable
- Leave as missing data if there are discrepancies in the values for other rows for the same ID for the variable

Example of the input data:

```
table <-
  data.frame(
    ID = c("A2", "A2", "A2", "B2", "B2", "C3", "C4", "D7", "D7", "D7", "E5", "E5", "E5", "E5", "F3"),
    Age = c("", 32, 32, "", 29, 43, 23, 34, "", 34, 24, "", "", 24, 35),
    Colour = c("Blue", "", "Pink", "Red", "Red", "Green", "Blue", "", "Yellow", "",
               "Purple", "Blue", "", "", "Orange"))

print(table)
```

```
   ID Age Colour
1  A2       Blue
2  A2  32       
3  A2  32   Pink
4  B2        Red
5  B2  29    Red
6  C3  43  Green
7  C4  23   Blue
8  D7  34       
9  D7     Yellow
10 D7  34       
11 E5  24 Purple
12 E5       Blue
13 E5           
14 E5  24       
15 F3  35 Orange
```

The output data I would like to get is:

```
new_table <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c("A2", "A2", "A2", "B2", "B2", "C3", "C4", "D7", "D7", "D7", "E5", "E5", "E5", "E5", "F3"),
    Age = c("", 32, 32, "", 29, 43, 23, 34, "", 34, 24, "", "", 24, 35),
    Colour = c("Blue", "", "Pink", "Red", "Red", "Green", "Blue", "", "Yellow", "",
               "Purple", "Blue", "", "", "Orange"),
    Age_New = c(32, 32, 32, 29, 29, 43, 23, 34, 34, 34, 24, 24, 24, 24, 35),
    Colour_New = c("Blue", "", "Pink", "Red", "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow",
                   "Yellow", "Yellow", "Purple", "Blue", "", "", "Orange"))
print(new_table)
```

```
   ID Age Colour Age_New Colour_New
1  A2       Blue      32       Blue
2  A2  32             32           
3  A2  32   Pink      32       Pink
4  B2        Red      29        Red
5  B2  29    Red      29        Red
6  C3  43  Green      43      Green
7  C4  23   Blue      23       Blue
8  D7  34             34     Yellow
9  D7     Yellow      34     Yellow
10 D7  34             34     Yellow
11 E5  24 Purple      24     Purple
12 E5       Blue      24       Blue
13 E5                 24           
14 E5  24             24           
15 F3  35 Orange      35     Orange
```

E.g. For ID = A2, because Row 2 & 3 of "Age" variable are the same (i.e. 32), Age_New for Row 1 can use "32" as the value. However, because the "Colour" variable in Row 1 = "Blue" and Row 3 = "Pink", there is discrepancy in the values for the same ID for this variable, therefore "Colour_New" remains empty.

I have found similar questions with answers, but the input data for these examples assume that there is only missing data in rows for the same ID and does not account for instances when there are discrepancies in values between rows for the same ID. The expected outcome for these questions is also to combine the rows together for the same ID, whereas I would like to keep each row separate even for the same ID.

- [R: Combine rows with same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72853248/r-combine-rows-with-same-id)
- [How to combine rows with the same identifier R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523082/how-to-combine-rows-with-the-same-identifier-r)

Appreciate any help with this - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here my proposition passing by 2 intermediate variables that could be removed `select(-n_age,-n_colour)` counting the number of `unique` var value by ID.

No discrepancy here is 1 unique value by ID

```r
library(dplyr)

new_table%>%
  mutate(Age=na_if(Age,""))%>%
  mutate(Colour=na_if(Colour,""))%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(n_Age=length(unique(Age[!is.na(Age)])))%>%
  mutate(n_colour=length(unique(Colour[!is.na(Colour)])))%>%
  mutate(Age2=ifelse(n_Age==1,unique(Age[!is.na(Age)]),Age))%>%
  mutate(colour2=ifelse(n_colour==1,unique(Colour[!is.na(Colour)]),Colour))
#> # A tibble: 15 × 9
#> # Groups:   ID [7]
#>    ID    Age   Colour Age_New Colour_New n_Age n_colour Age2  colour2
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>      <int>    <int> <chr> <chr>  
#>  1 A2    <NA>  Blue        32 "Blue"         1        2 32    Blue   
#>  2 A2    32    <NA>        32 ""             1        2 32    <NA>   
#>  3 A2    32    Pink        32 "Pink"         1        2 32    Pink   
#>  4 B2    <NA>  Red         29 "Red"          1        1 29    Red    
#>  5 B2    29    Red         29 "Red"          1        1 29    Red    
#>  6 C3    43    Green       43 "Green"        1        1 43    Green  
#>  7 C4    23    Blue        23 "Blue"         1        1 23    Blue   
#>  8 D7    34    <NA>        34 "Yellow"       1        1 34    Yellow 
#>  9 D7    <NA>  Yellow      34 "Yellow"       1        1 34    Yellow 
#> 10 D7    34    <NA>        34 "Yellow"       1        1 34    Yellow 
#> 11 E5    24    Purple      24 "Purple"       1        2 24    Purple 
#> 12 E5    <NA>  Blue        24 "Blue"         1        2 24    Blue   
#> 13 E5    <NA>  <NA>        24 ""             1        2 24    <NA>   
#> 14 E5    24    <NA>        24 ""             1        2 24    <NA>   
#> 15 F3    35    Orange      35 "Orange"       1        1 35    Orange
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Applied the code to my larger dataset and it works, thanks!